# phpmyadmin - extension mysqli is missing

Tags: php, apache, mysqli, phpmyadmin

i have a trouble with phpmyadmin , it show me this error :

> the mysqli extension is missing please check your PHP configuration ...

in php.ini i comment the line :

```
extension=mysqli
```

and restart apache but don't work

after that i uncomment it and change it to :

```
extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll"
```

after restarting apache : also doesn't work.
can someone help me ? some suggestion please ?
thank you in advance.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: i use windows 10